# Proving that a language is regular

Tags: regex, nlp, regular-language

The question is as follows: given a regular language L prove that the following languages are regular :

a) All the words (x XOR y) (x and y are words in the language)

b) All the words xy s.t. yx is a word in the language

For a) I have a vague idea on how to build a NFA that would accept the language, but for b) I'm clueless. I would appreciate any help!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a matter of defining an automaton recognising the language. Regular languages are closed under the reverse operation: if L is regular, then L<sup>R</sup> is regular.

The general idea of the proof is that, given the automaton that recognises L, you can transform it into an automaton that recognises L<sup>R</sup> by reversing the transitions.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is homework, but one way to get started is to assume you have the [prefix grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_grammar) for L and consider how to rewrite it to generate language (b).